# Least Squares problem?

Tags: performance-tuning, mathematical-optimization

Manifold $W$ is divided into 9 points. The value of the parameter $P$ at each point in manifold is represented by a certain number, and the partition itself is represented as a matrix:

```
P = {{1, 2, 3}, {-1, 0, 1}, {-3, -2, -1}}
```

There is also a matrix $J$ that depends on the value from the matrix $P$ at the selected point and on the variables $x,y$

```
J = {{x^2, 1, P[[i, j]]}, {0, x, -1}, {1, 2, y^4}}
```

I need help solving an optimization problem:

**1** Take each point from matrix $P$.

**2** Substitute it into the matrix $J$ and use the matrix norm $||J||$ formula at the given point.

**3** After that, I need to sum the squares of all the norms obtained at each point and divide by the number of partitions, i.e. use the formula:

$G=\frac{1}{n} q^Tq $,

where $q=\begin{bmatrix} ||J(x,y,P(1,1))|| & ||J(x,y,P(1,2))|| &  ||J(x,y,P(1,3))|| & \cdots & ||J(x,y,P(3,3))|| \end{bmatrix}$

**4** Find a combination of parameters $x,y$ that minimizes $G$, i.e.:

$\min_{x,y}G$

On the one hand, here is a ready-made algorithm. On the other hand, I have heard a lot about the possibilities of Mathematica in the field of optimization (and solving least-squares problems). Teach me how to use these possibilities.

I will be happy and grateful!

Comment: Since you already know that you have a sum-of-squares to optimize, you should be using the `"LevenbergMarquardt"` method in `FindMinimum[]`.

Comment: @J.M. I need block, that contains code for step 1-3 in algorithm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you description correctly, then there is no need to consider `P` as a matrix, a vector will do. (note I am using lower case names):

```
P = {1, 2, 3, -1, 0, 1, -3, -2, -1};
J = {{x^2, 1, #}, {0, x, -1}, {1, 2, y^4}} & /@ P
```

[image]

Unfortunately you did not specify which matrix norm you use. I will use the Frobenius norm,: sqrt of the sum of the squares of the matrix elements. For this we need the squares of the elements:

```
j^2
```

[image]

Our target function we want to minimize is then:

```
target = Total[Total[Flatten[#]^2] & /@ J]
(* 93 + 9 x^2 + 9 x^4 + 9 y^8 *)
```

It is now obvious, as only even powers of x and y appear, that the minimum is achieved for:

```
{x->0,y->0}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'll make a couple of points that I think are important:

1.$P$ - tabular data. It can be introduced into Mathematica, and vectorized. `P = {{1, 2, 3}, {-1, 0, 1}, {-3, -2, -1}}`; `pP = Transpose[{Flatten[Transpose[P]]}]`

2.Line `J = {{x^2, 1, #}, {0, x, -1}, {1, 2, y^4}} & /@ P` nice, but why does it form a set of vectors and not matrices?

3.We can use Frobenius, but I would like to get a matrix $nJ$, with the elements, that is norm of the $J$ is taken with the corresponding number at this point from $P$.

4.Then also vectorize $nJ$, get $G$ and than minimize.

Comment: We can work with $P$ in step 2 and use the norm at the same time. Then we get a vector of norms $nJ$, for example. And then either form $G$, or do Reshape.